# Replace config value in teamcity build step

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, web.config-transform

I have a build step in teamcity which allows me to replace web.config values with web.release.config values. I would like to add one more step - pass some parameter from teamcity to web.config. In my case it will be release version, which is part of connection string. The best idea I have is just to have some powershell script which will replace text in some file (web.config). Are there any better options?

Example web config

```
 <add key="Version" value="Replace me, please from teamcity"/>
 <add key="some key" value="example 2. version as part of some value #VERSION"/>
```

Comment: add you web.config file to question, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [File Content Replacer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/File+Content+Replacer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the creation of the web.config in release dependent of TeamCity, you can use [the web.config transformation syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx)

ie: To create a specific connection string:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDB" 
  connectionString="value for the deployed Web.config file" 
  xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I need pass to config teamcity value. As I said, I have step to transform config, but after that I need step to modify transformation result.